# Event not working properly after inserting new row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created an event that inserts values from table Loan, where members are yet to return a book that is due, in a table NotYetReturned. It does store the members in the table NotYetReturned, however, whenI insert a new row in the table Loan with a member that has a book overdue, it is not recorded in the table NotYetReturned.

[image: Table for Loan]

```
CREATE TABLE NotYetReturned LIKE Loan # First, create a table with the columns of Loan
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;    

CREATE EVENT DueDate_expired                    
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND          
DO INSERT INTO NotYetReturned SELECT * FROM Loan 
WHERE CURDATE() > DueDate and ReturnDate is NULL;

SELECT * FROM NotYetReturned;  # Check who hasn't returned their books yet
```

[image: This is correct]

```
INSERT Loan VALUE
('552-55-94354-34-4','301099-4448','25764510', '2019-01-01', NULL, '2019-02-01');

SELECT * FROM NotYetReturned; # The table doesn't contain the new insertion.
```

[image: This is not correct]

Should include the new row.

Comment: Why are you using events for this?  This seems like something one would do with a trigger.

Comment: It is part of an assignment to use the event function. Is that not possible?

Comment: Why do you want another table for that if you have a query with which you could always lookup that data based on current data not some probably stale records in another table? Unless having a very good reason and knowing what one does that's usually a bad idea. You could make a view of the query for convenience.

Comment: @nostres97 . . . It does not seem like a good solution.  I so do not like assignments that use inappropriate solutions to problems, unless they explicitly explain the trade-offs and why that method is chosen.

Comment: I see the points both of you are trying to make. However, for this specific assignment, I have a hard time figuring out which kind of event to use instead.

Comment: did you check the loan table whether the new record has got inserted or not? because, the insert query doesn't seem to be following the correct syntax.

Comment: And in the event creation select query, you should check whether the record is already present in 'NotYetReturned' table or not.

Comment: @sabhari karthik The insert query works here. The new row is added to Loan but not to NotYetReturned. In terms of your last comment, how do I check whether it is already present. I know to use "if not exists" but I can't add that anywhere in the event.

Comment: Does NotYetReturned and Loan table have the same structure? If not, specify columns in insert query as well as in select query.  To check whether it is present or not, you can use left join in the select query.

Comment: did specifying columns in insert and select work for you..??

Comment: When I created NotYetReturned, it was based on this CREATE TABLE NotYetReturned LIKE Loan, so the problem shouldn't be in the structure. I think that the problem lies in the event, because it updates every second, so therefore it should insert the new row in NotYetReturned automatically, when I insert a new row in Loan.

To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean by specifying the columns? If you mean by replacing * with the columns, then yes I've tried that.